# Compatibility between Android 8.1 Oreo recovery.img and 9.0 Pie

Tags: twrp, compatibility, infinix

I got Infinix x650 Android 8.1 Oreo `recovery.img` extracted with this command

```
$ abootimg -x recovery.img
#produced bootimg.cfg, zImage and ramdisk
```

I also downloaded `twrp.img` built for Infinix x650B running the same arch but running 9.1 Pie and `bootimg.cfg` with different offsets on extraction.

So I built a new TWRP named `x650_twrp.img` from x650 bootimg.cfg, x650 zImage and x650B ramdisk.

Will it work well on x650?